# run time layout manipulation

Tags: android, layout, android-activity, grid

I have a grid type of layout. When the app first loads, there are 3 buttons. I am using "Adapter" for the layout.
ONCLICK of the button, I want to refresh the same activity but with different set of 9 buttons.
Do I start a new Activity in all? OR Make a temporary activity to start the previous activity (and how)?
Since the ONCLICK event is written in the "Adapter" part of the code, starting new activity on click of the button is difficult. (is out of my knowledge).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the adapter class, we can start an activity using `context.startActivity(intent)` I did not know that we can access "start Activity" from adapter...
but now it's working just fine!!
Thanks a lot for your recommendation...

Answer (score 0):

if you are using adapter i.e., like baseadapter then you can try:

```
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

directly without starting activity again.

Comment: notifyDataSetChanged() this works if the databse is changed or how? and where to implement? in adapter class (baseAdapter) or the activity class?

Comment: It automatically refreshes your adapter contents  ,  in activity class when you changed the buttons count simply call this..

Answer (score 0):

If you want the user to go back to the 3 button view on click of Back button, it will be easier to have the 9 buttons in a different Activity.

Otherwise, you can have the 3 buttons and 9 buttons within two different LinearLayouts in the same activity and hide the second layout using setVisibility(LinearLayout.GONE);
On Click of the button, you can hide the first layout and enable the second one using  setVisibility(LinearLayout.VISIBLE);

Comment: The solution does not expect a fixed number of buttons. You can have any number of buttons within the LinerLayouts. When you hide the layout, all the content within the layout will get hidden.